Where is the opt out option so my answers don't get used by OpenAI?
I want to opt out of OpenAI taking my answers on SO and other SE website. How do I do that? I tried to look in my settings and there is nothing.
As an European member of SO, should I check with my local GDPR lawyers to get that done?
See point 1 of The right to erasure (Articles 17 & 19 of the GDPR).
Alternatively, where is the option to remove all my previous answers?

You can't. By using SO, you effectively licence your content for others to use. Also removal of your content is likely to be treated as vandalism and reversed.

OK, so question 2:  where is my option to remove ALL my previous asnwers ? Again, if I can't, this is a violation of GRPD in many European countries.

It's not a violation of GDPR, it's not personal information so GDPR does not apply.

I have rights to ask my data to be removed. Where is the option ?

https://www.dataprotection.ie/en/individuals/know-your-rights/right-erasure-articles-17-19-gdpr
"You have the right to have your data erased, without undue delay, by the data controller, if one of the following grounds applies:
Where your personal data are no longer necessary in relation to the purpose for which it was collected or processed."


The only right you have is to delete your personal information linked with the content you posted. Meaning the attribution.

https://policies.stackoverflow.co/data-request/

The data erasure thing does not apply in this case for your posts, since you are licensing them to SO when you post them. Personal information is covered by GDPR laws, and you can request to erase that (not the posts themselves). But please, do check with your local GDPR lawyers.

You can at max dissociate yourself from all your posts, you can't take them down since you've granted Stack Overflow an irrevocable licence when you posted your content.

The licence I agreed to what before the obviosu grab of SO by the OpenAI mafia

Related, on meta.se: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/399664/248731.

As an aside, because it apparently hasn't been mentioned yet, most or all data on SO (and elsewhere on the internet for that matter) is likely already in OpenAI's training data, even prior to the deal with them. The only thing you can do to avoid them getting your data is to stop producing more. Anything already out there is probably already in the dataset. Welcome to 2024

Everybody does not find it normal see here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/399619/our-partnership-with-openai They are disagreeing with the specifics of your post, not the general sentiment.

Reminder that you can express dissent, dissatisfaction, or even anger without either violating the Code of Conduct or otherwise just ranting unproductively.  As a bonus, it's usually more effective at getting what you want.  Several comments have been removed (by multiple moderators, not just me) for being more inappropriate than they were useful.

if that distracts you from thinking about the fact this website just sold out, fine.

Define "sold-out"? This website has always been a for-profit operation, so is it more sold-out than it used to be?

you can make a profit without enabling destruction of an ecosystem by using technology with dubious benefit and high environmental costs.

Are you referring to the high energy footprint of AI companies due to the power load they use to do their computations?

that + the stress put on mining rare earth to make their hardware.

I guess you missed the AI partnership with Google https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/398127/ This one is no different.

I'm not going to tell you what you should or shouldn't care about but for my own part I'm having a hard time knowing who the good companies and the bad companies are. Is OpenAI worse than Google? Or Microsoft?

They are all equally bad.

"I have rights to ask my data to be removed. Where is the option ?" No you don't. You legally forfeited any such right upon creating it and submitting it to the site. That's how the Creative Commons license works.

"The licence I agreed to what before the obviosu grab of SO by the OpenAI mafia" That's what open-source licenses are like. You don't get to restrict who uses the thing that you publish, either prejudicially or in retrospect, simply because of an ideological conflict with users, ethical qualm with something they did or anything else. By design. The CC licenses are the same idea for writing (and artwork) rather than code.

Where is my attribution in the great molasse hole that is any LLM ?

Same as all of the authors of fiction: whatever you and your lawyers can claw back.

Yea ... basically ... go talk to a lawyer about whether there is some way that you can wriggle out of the fact that you >>agreed<< that your contributions shall be published under a CCA license.  Personally: I don't think this is a fight you can win.  And from what I can judge from the comments ^^^, you don't seem to have the SO community behind you.

@JoelFalcou - Your attribution will be given when ChatGPT quotes whatever contribution you provided as it indicates any external sources it used. ChatGPT will provide sources in certain cases and responses. Especially if it quotes Wikipedia

I still wait to see CHatGPT generate a non bogus citation but w/e floats your boat. This site is dead to me.

@JoelFalcou - I see it all the time. Ask Copilot a question you know it will have to lookup on Wikipedia. Copilot is based on ChatGPT.

what can I say ? One of the few website I respected for their no AI BS stance just pulled the rug and all I see is a swamp of sycophants that just think this is normal. Sorry to sound like a troll, but the last thing I want to read is AI sycophant praising the Grace of Our Lord OpenAI.

@JoelFalcou people feel it's normal here because OpenAI was training their models on our content even before this deal and could have continued to do so (via the data dumps) without the deal. The only difference would be that the data dump is done every three months whereas this deal probably gives them live data. We can't really stop the company from making the deal either, it's a problem that comes with the license we post our content with.

@JoelFalcou If you feel that you have a valid legal claim, why not just make it through the proper channels instead of lashing out here? At the end of the day, you chose to provide content under a free license to a for-profit company. Said company is now planning to use that data, you know, for profit. If you want to go all surprised Pikachu over that and set a few cars on fire, go right ahead, but that doesn't make us AI sycophants.

You have to understand: i've already download the monthly dump of Stackoverflow. You can delete any of your questions or answers from Stackoverflow all you want, but all your answers are already on my computer - being used to train both carbon and silicon-based neural networks. That's the virtue of Stackoverflow: your knowledge now belongs to humanity. If you didn't want your knowledge in my brain, where i can now use your knowledge to help me write software for profit: then you shouldn't have contributed. Fortuntely i get to ignore GDPR requests.

In case anyone gets any clever ideas to sabotage human knowedge by deleting their content out of spite, the April 2024 dump of all the StackExchange sites is magnet:?xt=urn:btih:2EF5246C89679A43977B3B75EB6AB48BB15C73AE, and the December 2023 dump is magnet:?xt=urn:btih:414F55D7635A4C7FBE02C90C7D79B80D9046D4F2

See also https://archive.org/details/stackexchange for the latest data dump, and https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/224922/332043 for the full historical record

I feel the same in some ways. However also consider all the value you've already gotten out of having your content on this site and all the value you will continue to get in the future by keeping it up. It is still yours in every way that it always has been - it's just also someone else's now as well. And they will make real $ out of it and not give you any.

@AbdulAzizBarkat "You can at max dissociate yourself from all your posts..." Exactly and everyone in the whole world can because that is part of the CC license. The funny aspect about this question is the highly positive score. Not because the question is good but because probably many people think that OpenAI should not be able to legally have used that data (maybe now they are, but definitely not when they scraped it). So they upvote an only vaguely related question.

@IanBoyd The deletions are happening and not in a good way https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/posts/81387/revisions

@VladimirFГероямслава That post is already in the bicycles.stackexchange.com Posts.xml data dump <row Id="81387" PostTypeId="2" ParentId="81371" CreationDate="2021-10-26T20:33:05.847" Score="5" Body=" ... So it's safe; as is every other question and answer that anyone thinks will be funny to delete out of spite.

Copyright law doesn't give authors extremely powerful authority over their works? I thought it did. My understanding was that you can revoke permission.

@doug65536 Users posting on SO irrevocably give SE the rights to their content under CC-BY-SA.

For people stating it is permitted by the CreativeCommons license, it isn't. The CreativeCommons license that our content is licensed under is an attribution license. OpenAI does not attribute it's sources. This is a violation of the license. The only thing permitting this is the terms of service of StackExchange, and StackExchange as a company's disregard of the trust of their users.

@balupton it's more complicated than that. Stack Overflow (the company) has stated that they've given the data to OpenAI under the license the post is published under and have provided them proper information so that they can attribute. This means Stack Overflow is meeting the license requirements. On the OpenAI side it's more complicated because the licensing of the generated content is under debate on whether it is considered fair use or not.

Short-answer, you can't.
The longer answer is mostly in the comments, but the core issue is that:

Questions and Answers you've posted are not personal data as defined by the GDPR.

When you posted content on any SE site, you did so under the Licensing Terms of the Terms of Service:

This means that you cannot revoke permission for Stack Overflow to publish, distribute, store and use such content and to allow others to have derivative rights to publish, distribute, store and use such content.


... as well as the Creative Commons CC BY-SA 4.0 as discussed here


I am not a lawyer, but there may be some exceptions under the GDPR if:

Any of your posts contain personal information (which they shouldn't). In that case, you could Flag an answer to have a Moderator redact the personal content.

You can also, as mentioned in the comments, request to have your personal account information removed from the SE system. You seem to already be aware of this, however, as I believe I saw a comment from you to that effect (which I can't find or has now been deleted). As you know, this will keep the content on the website, but remove your personal account details from it, as with other questions/answers from deleted accounts that you've assuredly seen here.
Not that I believe you intend to do so, but for any users considering it, please keep in mind that self-deleting existing content which is considered useful here may be a violation of the Code of Conduct and would likely result in the content being undeleted and locked.
Also from your comments:

The licence I agreed to what before the (OpenAI Deal)

This does not matter, of course. The SE/OpenAI deal does not appear to violate the existing agreement between you and SE. You cannot revoke your "irrevocable" license you have given to SE on this basis. If you feel it does violate the existing licensing terms, you can, of course, consult an attorney who is more of an expert in IP/licensing disputes (vs. GDPR), but as you can imagine, this will likely be expensive and fruitless.

How can they prove that anyone agreed to the terms of service? I don't get how those can be legally binding since nobody actively signed anything or identified themselves. How can SO prove that a specific person has been informed and is agreeing on the terms? Obviously a deal which one party wasn't informed about and/or didn't agree upon by explicitly signing it is not valid.

@Lundin they have this note at the sign up page: "By clicking “Sign up”, you agree to our terms of service and acknowledge you have read our privacy policy." One can argue this in court but since this notice is IMO put in a noticeable spot its going to be difficult to win. Of course one can say they didn't read the actual terms but that's entirely on the user.

@AbdulAzizBarkat 1) That was added after a whole lot of users had already signed up. 2) They have changed the ToS retroactively, making the terms invalid to those who had already signed up 3) They still can't prove that one particular physical person agreed to it/was informed about it. Could be a friend, a hacker, a burglar, a cat walking across the keyboard.

They only need to "prove" anything if sued about it. You can argue that your account was created by your cat if you want to sue them. I'd check with an actual lawyer. Maybe all your posts belong to your cat now.

@Lundin I'll leave point 1 & 2 upto the company, but point 3 wouldn't really help you. If you say that your friend created the account it will only pull your friend along into the mess, if you read the terms of service you'll see there is a clause for indemnification meaning your friend then takes all responsibility if you sue Stack Overflow with regards to your usage of their account. I'm quite sure there would be some clause somewhere that prevents you from sharing accounts as well.

@AbdulAzizBarkat The point is that I can just say that I have no idea about the ToS and didn't agree to any of it, and nobody can prove it otherwise since I didn't take any legally binding action, such as signing a document. Whoever clicked some accept button isn't important - I can just say I have no idea who did it but it wasn't me.

@Lundin "Whoever clicked some accept button isn't important" then you can't really sue for the account you talk about, since you are effectively a third party (Even proving that you are the actual author of your content on Stack Overflow becomes difficult in that case). That argument basically nullifies any claim you could have made. Point 1 & 2 from your comment is what you can actually argue upon.

@AbdulAzizBarkat The account is tied to my e-mail address so proving that is super easy.

@Lundin not really, if a third person created the account for you Stack Overflow could argue that the content could have also been posted by them. You could bring the third person in but then comes the indemnification clause and the third person has also now broken the terms of service since they require the account holder to be an individual. Anyway this is getting a bit off-topic, lets end this conversation here.

"Questions and Answers you've posted are not personal data as defined by the GDPR." - yes they are, at least if they are associated with your name! Far too many people assume "personal data" is a synonym of "PII"; it is not. The GDPR defines as personal data all information relating to an identifi[ed/able] natural person. Here's a Dutch lawyer specialising in internet law specifically saying the authorship relation counts and thus online posts and messages are personal data: https://blog.iusmentis.com/2018/04/03/geldt-het-vergeetrecht-onder-de-avg-ook-bij-forumdiscussies/

(None of this is to say that the GDPR grants anyone a right to have their posts deleted. For one thing, the Right to Erasure has exceptions; perhaps some apply. For another, I would assume anonymisation, which Stack Overflow offers, is a valid way to implement a Right to Erasure request since it results in the data no longer being personal data (although puzzlingly guidance about Right to Erasure I can find online, including from the UK's privacy regulator doesn't mention this option at all).

@MarkAmery Fair enough - I think it's probably more accurate to say, though, that the posts themselves are not personal data, but may contain personal date.  As noted in my answer, the user certainly has the right to remove any personal data in their posts.  For a "name", however, the user is perfectly free to do that simply by using an anonymous username.  Then their posts will not have the "name" PII.

Best way to fight this is to stop providing content, see how SO reacts losing its users.

Best way was to not post here, even before open AI was founded.

@MarkAmery in that case, personal data is the link of the post to your account. Once that link is gone, the post contains no more personal data. Also, notice that exceptions to this apply, like if you try to disassociate to avoid penalties.

Wouldn't removing that link break afoul of the BY requierment of the license? If SO wants to keep the content, they have to do so by respecting the license and the full license.

@LuisMachuca There are a lot of questions without good answers surrounding the legality of how SO has handled licensing, particularly wrt. license upgrades. I think the only way we'll get an answer is if someone involves lawyers.

The best way to protest is to no longer contribute.
I'm not in the top 1% like Glyph
https://mastodon.social/@glyph/112412335865418867
but like them, I will not contribute to the creation of an automated data laundering machine, built for the express purpose of making my work in open source invisible, and for denying me power
https://githubcopilotlitigation.com/
https://matthewbutterick.com/chron/this-copilot-is-stupid-and-wants-to-kill-me.html
I suggest we all do the same
https://bristoluniversitypress.co.uk/resisting-ai

@NickleDave: I take a dim view of brigading to up- or downvote questions and answers here. The results are inauthentic, and I regard such actions as unethical.

@PresidentJamesK.Polk While in most situations, I agree that vote brigades are bad, I think upvoting a meta post (assuming no fraudulent means are used) as described there is a completely reasonable way to express an opinion on matters relating to how the site is run, and certainly a better one than defacing content on a site that is, despite being run by a for-profit company, nonetheless a public resource.  After all, one needs to have contributed to the site somehow in order to be able to vote here, so that ensures voters have at least some stake in the issue.

We submit content under the condition that it's published under CC BY-SA 4.0 and is free to use by anyone forever.  OpenAI does not follow CC BY-SA 4.0, so they are not legally allowed to use our content.

@endolith Stack Overflow's (i.e., the company's) statement on attribution requirements for partnerships is here, including a specific mention of license compliance.

@endolith Except someone from Creative Commons has expressed the opinion that likely training AI is fair use, and thus exempt from conditions such as attribution. And see also this faq

@MarkRotteveel to be fair that's not always going to be the case. If the model produces output which does not differ much from the original content used for the training it shouldn't really be considered fair use and should still follow the respective license terms. The model itself can't also be considered fair use (I am considering three separate things with regards to license here the training data, the resulting model and the output from the model), and should be licensed properly considering the training data. I do agree that in most cases the output can be considered fair use though.

@SylvainGantois "... see how SO reacts losing its users." SO is losing users for many years. The company reacts very slowly and not really as desired. I fully agree with you though. I surely would contribute more if SO was a "better" company, so this effect exists, but I think the even more important idea would not only stop posting here but also start posting somewhere else and taking legal action against OpenAI. But at the same time may be sufficient to change the World.

@AbdulAzizBarkat "The model itself can't also be considered fair use..." Very interesting questions that unfortunately the courts will have to answer and they may need many years to solve that problem. If only they were faster somehow. I could imagine that a lot of fair uses together also end up in a total unfair use, but where exactly to draw the line. And that would also probably mean the death of AI as we know it, which seems to be difficult to maintain politically. AI was promoted as the future instead. OpenAI and others may simply be thieves that will get away.

@endolith "OpenAI does not follow CC BY-SA 4.0, so they are not legally allowed to use our content." Some people think we submit content under two different licenses actually. See Can SE just resell our data, relicense it and remove the attribution requirement?

@AbdulAzizBarkat That depends on if and how training data is retained in the model. In general, LLMs will not retain the training data itself (which doesn't mean that they couldn't reproduce it).

@NoDataDumpNoContribution If that were true, what incentive would there be for people to contribute for free?  The whole point of Stack Exchange is that it's open-source.

@MarkRotteveel LLMs do retain the training data verbatim in their trained weights, and even if they didn't, they're still a derivative work. https://arxiv.org/abs/2202.07646 https://arxiv.org/abs/2301.13188

@endolith Ask people why they contribute and you'll know. Maybe they just want to help others, maybe they like to work for free, maybe they believe that StackOverflow is one of the good ones, while it's only a company making profit. They might a bit naive too (no offense). All would be good reasons to continue contributing.

This policy is what makes me keep my contributions to an absolute minimum. I usually prefer to post elsewhere. This kind of "it's ours forever" grab leaves a bitter taste. That and the creepy data dump. The data dump really could be problematic under GDPR because if someone disassociates their answer, the old dumps may, from a legal point of view, need to be redacted if they still contain the association of the user and the answer.
